# how to handle multiple target translation for a source term in MS Hub dictionary files

Tags: microsoft-translator

When preparing the dictionary file of a language for MS Hub training, I come across some source terms which have more than one preferred translations. Should I put them into two different entries or what is the best practice for such occasion? I am wondering if this would affect the behaviour of the system to recognise the terms/ translation.

Besides, is it also possible to leave some terms in certain target languages empty if I want to create a multi-lingual dictionary? This would save me some time instead of preparing a glossary for every language pair that has the same source languages. But I am not sure if leaving the term empty in the target language would cause the model to regard that term as an empty entry in the translation...

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A phrase dictionary applies with 100% probability. You can have multiple source phrases map to the same target phrase, but you cannot have multiple target phrases for the same source in the dictionary. You can have the phrase in your regular training material, and Translator will prefer the variant matching your context best.

It is always a better choice to let the system learn the words and phrases you prefer from your training material, within full sentences. Translator learns the inflection and the context from your example sentences. You can consider the dictionary a crutch if you do not have enough full-sentence training material providing examples of your phrases.

The multilingual dictionary should be smart enough to ignore the empty cells. I am not 100% sure on that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion!